# How to autorun and install an android .apk from SD card?

Tags: android, installation, apk, sd-card, autorun

Can anyone tell me the code to autorun and install an .apk as soon as you put in the
SD card(with the .apk file) when the Android Device is switched on??

Answer (score 2):

There is no such facility in Android, sorry. It is possible that some third-party apps might offer this, to monitor external storage for new files and install any APKs found there.